# XSLT 2.0 Need to output up to 10 records per employee

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML file with employees. Each employee can have any where from 1 - 10 certification numbers. I need to output the employee number and 10 certification spaces regardless of how many certifications they have. The output file is a pipe delimited file so if an employee has 2 certifications then the output should be:

12231|cert-123|cert-1234|||||||||

This is part of my original XSLT to only provide the certifications they have:

```
<xsl:template match="ws:Worker_Sync">
    <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ws:Worker"> </xsl:apply-templates>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ws:Worker">
    <Record>
        <EEID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ws:Summary/ws:Employee_ID"/>
        </EEID>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="ws:Qualifications/ws:Certification_Achievement">
            <CERT_ID >
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="ws:Certification_ID"/>
            </CERT_ID>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Record>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<xsl:value-of select="for $pos in (1 to 10) return string(ws:Certification_ID[$pos])" separator="|"/>` to output a piple separated list of 10 certification ids.